Flickering kitchen downlighters
UPDATE 3:
So based on Update 2 I placed the new bulbs in the slots where new slots had worked and old bulbs in slots where there new ones hadn't. This I thought would work!
The new bulbs started to flicker after 20 minutes in the slots they had previously worked.
All bets are off. I'm stumped.
UPDATE 2:
Interestingly, its not just the bulbs. The fittings matter too. I removed all bulbs. I got 1 bulb (a new one) and place it in each slot for 30 minutes.
2 of them were fine, 2 ~ immediately flickered.
I did several passes to account for temp.
So, it seems like its neither the bulbs nor the transformer.
The old bulbs are fine in all of the fittings
UPDATE 1:
Interestingly, the 6.1W bulb (the new one) actually should be ~9W based on 750mA * 12V  and the 8W bulb should be 8.4 based on p=IV
I also took all the bulbs out bar one old one. No flickering. If it was down to load on the transformer then we would expect more flickering as more bulbs were removed!
ORIGINAL:
In my kitchen ceiling I have downlighters. These were fitted before I bought the house and they lasted during my tenure at least 4 years.
I bought some new LED bulbs from B&Q. These start flickering after around 5 minutes. I took one of the old working bulbs and placed it into the slot where the new bulb was flickering and the old bulb worked fine.
The old bulbs are  GU5.3 8W 3000K 12V-50HZ at 700mA
They are here online https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-gu5-3-8w-621lm-reflector-led-light-bulb/1324494_BQ.prd
The new are  GU5.3 6.1W 2700K 12V at 750mA.
These are here https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-6-1w-warm-white-led-utility-light-bulb/5059340199405_BQ.prd?storeId=&&&&&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw3P-2BhAEEiwA3yPhwHiUJca86m1XIdSuOiqSJbn7jMni9rZCtCIjGiyfie6uB6ul-nWiDRoCTRYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds
Both are Diall branded.
Before I buy new bulbs I want to confirm my suspicion that the issue is down to the lower ampage (and therefore wattage) placing insufficient load on the step down transformer? Or are the new bulbs garbage?
The old bulbs are no longer available for purchase!

Your new bulbs cause the problem that is not present with the old bulbs.  The obvious answer is the issue is with the bulbs. The bulbs use what power is provided by the transformer. They do not change the performance of the transformer.
Historically,but not absolutely, there are fewer issues with more expensive bulbs made by name brand manufacturers. Wattage should not be a factor.

So, I bought several packs on independent shopping trips all of the same new type and they all exhibit the same issue!
Are you suggesting that the different wattage and ampage etc are not the issue and its a manufacturing issue? They are the same brand as the existing working bulbs!

The old bulbs were probably manufactured in a different plant.  Now new bulbs are made cheaper and probably imported.  If you want to believe it's the wattage, I cannot stop you.

I'm not saying you're wrong merely asking because I've had issues with transformers previously when the load was too low! Which brand would you recommend if you suspect the new products? I'm trying to avoid wasting more products

I like to stick with Cree or Ge, but truthfully flickering has been encountered with some of those bulbs too.

The issue isn't "different plant", though it is quite common for companies to move and/or outsource manufacturing, and sometimes the same design outsourced can end up with different results. Far more likely is a different driver design - i.e., the part that converts from 12V 50 Hz AC to the DC voltage needed by the LEDs. And since that is (a) not something people shop for and (b) buried inside the bulb base and not accessible, it is not something normally included in the specs.

It feels like there is a difference in the actual design/technology between the old/new bulbs, as evidenced by different wattage, current draw, and "temperature". Why that might cause flickering I've no idea, but given your several, independent packs, it feels like there's an inherent incompatibility.

interestingly, its not just the bulbs. The fittings matter too. I removed all bulbs. Got 1 bulb (a new one) and place it in each slot for 30 minutes.
2 of them were fine, 2 immediately flickered.
I did several passes to account for temp.
Seems like its neither the bulbs nor the transformer.
The old bulbs are fine in all of the fittings

So based on Update 2 I placed the new bulbs in the slots where new slots had worked and old bulbs in slots where there new ones hadn't. This I thought would work!
The new bulbs started to flicker after 20 minutes in the slots they had previously worked.
All bets are off. I'm stumped.  Maybe buy new bulbs and a new transformer.
